# SQL Server Update query single quote issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am taking input from the user & updating it in a table. I directly execute the update query from C# code.

`[GoalsDesc]` is dynamically set with a string variable. The issue here is the user inputs single quotes `'` which crashes the update query.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Goals] 
SET [GoalsDesc] = 'Child is equivalent to Child. However, I'd like to add a unit test to ensure that this is always the case. And this is where I'm stuck.',
    [ActiveStatus] = 1,
    [Status] = 2
```

How to handle this in an update query?

Comment: Cant you use parameter binding? Or at least escape the users inputs. Never ever build queries directly from user input.

Comment: Do a web search for "SQL Injection" and "SQL Server".

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use parameterised query. Well you can handle the single quote in query by doubling them up. like this -

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Goals] 
SET [GoalsDesc] = 'Child is equivalent to Child. However, I''d like to add a unit test to ensure that this is always the case. And this is where I''m stuck.'
, [ActiveStatus] = 1
, [Status] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Krishnraj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49082102/1666800), you can also try these methods too:

**Method 1: using Char(39)**

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Goals] 
SET [GoalsDesc] = 'Child is equivalent to Child. However, I'+char(39)+'d like to add a unit test to ensure that this is always the case. And this is where I'+char(39)+'m stuck.'
, [ActiveStatus] = 1
, [Status] = 2
```

**Method 2: using QUOTED_IDENTIFIER**

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
UPDATE [dbo].[Goals] 
SET [GoalsDesc] = "Child is equivalent to Child. However, I'd like to add a unit test to ensure that this is always the case. And this is where I'm stuck."
, [ActiveStatus] = 1
, [Status] = 2
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

Comment: I suggest one use the ISO SQL standard `QUOTED_IDENTIFER ON` as that is required for many SQL Server features like indexed views, filtered indexes, etc. It is best to use a parameterized query as that avoids SQL injection and provides a number of other benefits.